Is there a simple way to check if an expression is a linear combination of another set of expressions?
Is there a simple way to check if an expression is a linear combination of another set of expressions?
EDIT: The question was not very clear so let me re-state it:
What is the quickest technique to tell if an expression of the type
$$4b_1-b_3+b_4=0$$
is or isn't a linear combination other 2 or more given expressions like for example
$$2b_1-b_2+b_4=0$$
$$-2b_2+b_3+b_4=0$$
(In this case, by close examination and some trial an error I can tell that it is, but I wouldn't call that a "technique").
All that follows is context.
Today I discovered that, while the RREF of a given matrix is unique, when the augmented column has parameters, the parametric RREF form may be not unique (or at least look not unique).
I was doing homework with my daughter today and there was a problem that said "Find the conditions that $b_1$, $b_2$, $b_3$ and $b_4$ must meet so the following system of equations is consistent".
And there was a system of 4 equations with 4 unknown where the independent terms (at the right-hand side of the equal sign) were $b_1$, $b_2$, $b_3$ and $b_4$
Building the augmented matrix and doing row operations we arrived to the RREF where, surely enough, the last two rows were all zeros in the coefficient parts and some linear combinations of $b_1$, $b_2$, $b_3$ and $b_4$ on the augmented part.
The problem was multiple choice. So there were a number of options with conditions for $b_1$, $b_2$, $b_3$ and $b_4$ (one or two linear combination of those equaled to zero) and there was the dreaded "none of the above". We quickly discarded the options that had only one linear combination of $b_1$, $b_2$, $b_3$ and $b_4$ equaled to zero (because we needed two) and from the ones with two, none of them matched what we got.
I said "well, the RREF is unique, so unless we did something wrong, it has to be none of the above", and immediately panicked...
If we take the two linear combinations of $b_1$, $b_2$, $b_3$ and $b_4$ that are equal to zero (like the ones that we had in the all-zero-coefficient rows), lets call them $L_1=0$ and  $L_2=0$, then ANY new linear combination of those linear combinations, of the form $L_3=r*L_1+s*L_2$ would also be equal to zero and hence $L_3$ (or another $L_4$, etc...)  could take the place of $L_1$ or $L_2$ in the RREF matrix, because any row operation that I do with the rows $R3$ and $R4$ would be a linear combination of all zeros in the coefficients part (which will always yield more zeros) and of a linear combination of $L_1$ and $L_2$ in the augmented part (independent terms).
I feel lucky that, just with some careful observation, we were able to find that some linear combination of $L_1$ and $L_2$ did in fact match one of the options, so the correct answer was not "none of the above" after all.
But is there a simple technique to tell, in general, if, given $b_1$, $b_2$, $b_3$ and $b_4$, two linear combinations of them $L_3$ and $L_4$ (found in the answer options) are in fact themselves linear combinations of another two linear combinations of $b_1$, $b_2$, $b_3$ and $b_4$ ($L_1$ and $L_2$) that we found in our RREF matrix? With "simple" I mean, to give you an idea, not using a determinant since they have not covered it yet in their class.
Here is the specific example:
The system of equation (that we had to make consistent) was:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
x_1-2x_2+3x_3-4x_4 &=b_1 \\
2x_1+3x_2-4x_3+5x_4 &=b_2 \\
4x_1-x_2+2x_3-3x_4 &=b_3 \\
7x_2-10x_3+13x_4 &=b_4
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$
From which we built the augmented matrix:
$$\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & -2 & 3 & -4 & b_1 \\
2 & 3 & -4 & 5 & b_2 \\
4 & -1 & 2 & -3 & b_3 \\
0 & 7 & -10 & 13 & b_4 \\
\end{array}
\right]$$
And from there, doing row operations we got to the following RREF:
$$\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & 0 & \frac{1}{7} & -\frac{2}{7} & b_1+2\frac{b_4}{7} \\
0 & 1 & -\frac{10}{7} & \frac{13}{7} & \frac{b_4}{7} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2b_1-b_2+b_4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2b_2+b_3+b_4 \\
\end{array}
\right]$$
So for the system of equations to be consistent we need to have:
$2b_1-b_2+b_4=0$ (let me call that $L_1=0$) and $-2b_2+b_3+b_4=0$ (say $L_2=0$).
That didn't match any of the multiple-choice options, but one of them was:
$2b_1+b_2-b_3=0$ (let's say $L_3=0$) and $4b_1-b_3+b_4=0$ (let's say $L_4=0$)
Careful examination reveals that $L_3=L_1-L_2=0-0=0$, so that's equivalent.
Furter careful examination reveals that $L_4=2L_1-L_2=2\cdot0-0=0$, so that's equivalent too.
So the two conditions we found using the RREF are equivalent to the conditions in one of the multiple-choice options, and hence that option is correct.
But I don't want to rely on careful examination!!!! I feel lucky, not skillful, that we found the correct answer.
By the way, this also means that I could put, in the last two rows of the augmented column, any two mutually-independent linear combinations of $L_1$ and $L_2$. Any such linear combination would still be equal to zero, just like $L_1$ and $L_2$, so the RREF is still unique, but when working with letters (parameters) instead of numbers the same RREF matrix can have many (infinite) different visual forms, which is something that I had not realized before.
For example, these two matrices are both the same RREF of the original system of equations, but they look different (one with $L_1$ and $L_2$ and the other with $L_3$ and $L_4$ in the last two rows).
$\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & 0 & \frac{1}{7} & -\frac{2}{7} & b_1+2\frac{b_4}{7} \\
0 & 1 & -\frac{10}{7} & \frac{13}{7} & \frac{b_4}{7} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2b_1-b_2+b_4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2b_2+b_3+b_4 \\
\end{array}
\right]$ vs $\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & 0 & \frac{1}{7} & -\frac{2}{7} & b_1+2\frac{b_4}{7} \\
0 & 1 & -\frac{10}{7} & \frac{13}{7} & \frac{b_4}{7} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2b_1+b_2-b_3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4b_1-b_3+b_4 \\
\end{array}
\right]$

What is an expresion?

I think this also hinges on how you define "simple"

@coper.hat, in the context of the specific situation we were in, an "expression" is itself a linear combination of 4 parameters $b_1$, $b_2$, $b_3$ and $b_4$. For example, how can I can easily check if  $4b_1-b_3+b_4$ is or isn't a linear combination of $2b_1-b_2+b_4=0$ and $-2b_2+b_3+b_4=0$? (which in this case it is)

@Joseph_Kopp, with "simple" I mean to be able to check quickly in a quiz if the solution you found is equivalent to one of the multiple-choice options, with the elements that you would have after the 1st 2 weeks of Linear Algebra where so far the only thing you saw is how to convert a system of linear equations into a RREF augmented matrix (they didn't even learn determinant yet). So you would need to use mostly things you already learnt before in previous classes, like basic non-matrix algebra.

https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/jmeth/DEFall18/LinAlg3.html#:~:text=if%20the%20right%20hand%2Dmost,is%20called%20a%20free%20variable.
